# CSS animations infinite overlap

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to loop the animations from the beginning after the last one ends. Writing this line makes the animations overlap:

`animation: FadeIn 5s infinite;`

```css
@keyframes FadeIn {
    0% {left: 0%; opacity: 0;}
    10% {left: 5%; opacity: 1;}  
    100% {left: 110%; opacity: 0;}
}

.testing > div:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 5s;
    transition:opacity 1 10s;
}
 
.testing > div:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 10s;
}
 
.testing > div:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 15s;
}
 
.testing > div:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 20s;
}
 
.testing > div:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: 25s;
}
 
.testing > div:nth-child(6) {
    animation-delay: 30s;
}

.testing > div:nth-child(7) {
    animation-delay: 35s;
}
 
.testing > div:nth-child(8) {
    animation-delay: 40s;
}
 
.testing > div:nth-child(9) {
    animation-delay: 45s;
}
 
.testing > div:nth-child(10) {
    animation-delay: 50s;
}

.testing > div {
   opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 4em;
    width: 95%;
    font-size: 13px;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation: FadeIn 5s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="testing">
              
 <div>Green</div>
 <div>Blue</div>
 <div>Yellow</div>
 <div>Red</div>
 <div>Purple</div>
 <div>Brown</div>
 <div>Silver</div>
 <div>Grey</div>
 <div>Gold</div>
 <div>Black</div>

</div>
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: if I undestand well you need to assign a different top value for each div...

Comment: actually problem is this you're applying `position: absolute` to all div's like this `.testing > div` remove div and apply `display:inline-block`

Comment: @MerajKhan Thanks. But removing the div makes all elements show at the same time. Can you explain a bit more about what you suggested?

Comment: @DaFois Thanks. Can you explain a bit more about what you meant by assigning a different top value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `divs` are overlapping because`position: absolute` has put them in the same place.

`animation-delay` lets you stagger when each `div` appears to animate. However, it won't create the effect you want because after one loop of the animation the `div` returns to the beginning and overlaps the next `div`.

An alternative method would be to wrap the `divs` in a container and animate the container instead.

**Setup**

1. Outer container that will hold the animation. Apply `overflow: hidden` so that the animated `div` doesn't create a horizontal scrollbar.
2. Inner container which will be animated. The width of this container should be `100% x the number of child elements`.

   For 10 elements, the container width is 1000%

   For 20 elements, the container width is 2000%
3. Nested elements are floated to appear inline. The width of each element is `100/the number of elements`.

   For 10 elements, the width is 10%

   For 20 elements, the width is 5%
4. The end position of the animation is the width of the animated container (with a negative value).

   For 10 elements, `right: -1000%`

   For 20 elements, `right: -2000%`
5. The `animation-duration` should be proportional to the number of elements in the animated container - use a longer duration with more elements.

[fiddle with 10 elements](https://jsfiddle.net/jjcrdy5u/2/)

[fiddle with 20 elements](https://jsfiddle.net/p8subj2g/1/)

[fiddle with styling](https://jsfiddle.net/5s4g71ou/1/)

```css
@keyframes FadeIn {
  0% {
    right: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    /* right = same value as .animate width */
    right: -1000%;
  }
}

.testing {
  height: 12em;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.animate {
  /* width = number of elements x 100% */
  width: 1000%;
  position: absolute;
  /* adjust the duration proportional to the number of elements */
  animation: FadeIn 25s linear infinite;
}

.animate div {
  float: right;
  /* width = 100% / number of elements */
  width: 10%
}





/* create opacity effect */
.testing:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 10em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="testing">
  <div class="animate">
    <div>Green</div>
    <div>Blue</div>
    <div>Yellow</div>
    <div>Red</div>
    <div>Purple</div>
    <div>Brown</div>
    <div>Silver</div>
    <div>Grey</div>
    <div>Gold</div>
    <div>Black</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. Can you explain a bit about your code? What you meant by "for 10 elements, multiply container width by 10"? If I have 20 elements, I should change the `width` to 12000px?

Comment: @LorekBryanson Basically yes. You want each element to have 100% of the width of the container. So the container needs to be (the number of the elements) x (the width of one element). I've used pixels in the snippet above, it might work with % I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried to add in another 10 elements and updated the width, but changing the width only makes the element to animate slower. And instead of looping through all 20 elements, it only loops through first 10 elements and have the rest 10 element appear under the previous elements. Here's the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/LorekB/Lmp44xfs/7/)

Comment: You needed to tweak a few more values. Here is updated code https://jsfiddle.net/f1wrzepx/1/ -- I will update my answer in a bit with a clearer explanation for you